# GroupBy with Count

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have list `testList` returned and it has **5** items in it with proper values.

```
var testList = _context.LectureReportStudent
    .Include(x => x.LectureReport)
    .Include(x => x.LectureReport.Lecture)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Where(x => stuIds.Contains(x.LectureReport.LectureId))
    .Select(x => new StudentModel
    {
        Name = x.Student.FirstName + "" + x.Student.LastName,
        Position = x.Student.JobTitle,
        JobId = x.LectureReport.LectureId,
        StudentId = x.StudentlId,
        LectureId = x.LectureReportId,
        Date = x.Date
    };
```

I further `GroupBy` this list on `StudentId`.

```
var result = testList.GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
```

Each item has the following model

```
Date, DaysOnLecture, LectureCount, LectureId, LectureReportId, Name, StudentId, Position
```

I am trying to take the Count of DaysOnLecture, LectureCount attributes.

> LectureCount means the no. of times student attended lecture (it is defined in my model).
>
> DatsOnLecture the no of days student attended this lecture (it is defined in my model).

I am struck with logic. Any idea?

Comment: in projection you don't select properties that you want to count

Comment: I did not add them because they are calculated values. For Instance if i add them what value i should assign them?

Comment: I've started a Fiddle to try to clarify what you're trying to accomplish: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SB02lQ

Comment: When you say, "Each item has the following model...", what is the item?

Comment: Thanks i think i am reaching to solution. in your example result gives three IEnumerable lists ... Under 1st list i have 2 records (items) with lectureId and LectureReportId. Under second list i have again 2 records(items) with lectureId and LectureReportId. Under 3rd list i have 1 record (item) with ReportId and lectureReportId. My requirement is take count of LectureId and LectureReportId (Distinct). Kind help me.

Comment: Sure. I've updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Is a `LectureId` different than a `LectureReportId`? I.e., is this a primary-foreign key relationship?

Comment: Yes Shaun it is primary-foreign key

Comment: What's the difference between a count of `LectureId` and a count of `LectureReportId` if it's a primary-foreign key relationship?

Comment: Shaun, thanks for all this but i am still missing the point. I have posted another question with correct data i am using. please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586572/linq-groupby-multiple-columns-and-count

Comment: @user1874957 No worries. My answer isn't yet an answer (which might actually be an abuse of the SO forum.) Rather, it was an attempt at a closer understanding of your question. It was interesting to explore, and it sounds like you found an answer. That's a good thing. It seems like we were able to clarify the issue here, and that you're other question lead to the solution. I also asked another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583931/group-on-two-columns-and-create-two-separate-counts

Answer (score 0):

```
var counts = testList.GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
                     .Select(g =>
    new
    {
        StudentId = g.Key,
        TotalDays = g.Sum(gg => gg.DaysOnLecture),
        TotalLecture = g.Sum(gg => gg.LectureCount)
    });
```

If you want total per LectureId, then you have to do further grouping by LectureId on the data for each student