# Group on Two Columns and Create Two Separate Counts

Tags: c#, linq

## Question

We have a table of `StudentId` and `LectureId`, and we want to know two things.

1. `CountStudentId` How many times each `StudentId` occurs.
2. `CountStudentIdLectureId` How many times each `StudentId` + `LectureId` pair occurs.

(2) is done in below. (1) is not.

In other words, **how can we count two different groups in a single query?**

Another way of thinking about this, would be to count the `StudentId` + `LectureId` group and also sum that count for each `StudentId`.

## What we've tried

The following query groups on `StudentId` + `LectureId`. It does count how many times the `StudentId` + `LectureId` group occurs. It doesn't count how many times the `StudentId` group occurs. That's what we also want.

```
var query = joinTable
    .GroupBy(jt => new { jt.StudentId, jt.LectureId } )
    .Select(g => new {
        StudentId = g.Key.StudentId,
        LectureId = g.Key.LectureId, 
        CountStudentId =  -1, // Count all StudentId (i.e. 10)?
        CountStudentIdLectureId = g.Count()
    });
```

This is the result we're currently receiving. In each row, the `-1` value should be `10` (because we seeded the `JoinTable` with ten of each `StudentId`) and we haven't achieved that.

## Results we want to achieve

...but with `10` instead of `-1` in each case.**

```
StudentId      LectureId      CountStudentId   CountStudentLectureId
0              0              -1               3              
0              1              -1               3              
0              2              -1               3              
0              3              -1               1              
1              0              -1               2              
1              1              -1               3              
1              2              -1               3              
1              3              -1               2
```

In those results, we need `CountStudentId` to be `10` not `-1` (the latter is just a placeholder for now.)

That's the expected result, because each `StudentId` occurs `10` times and because the sum of `CountStudentLectureId` for each `StudentId` is `10`, which is just two ways of saying the same thing.

## Full demo code

This is the [full Fiddle code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DOjsLH) for reference.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var joinTable = SeedJoinTable();

        var query = joinTable
            .GroupBy(jt => new { jt.StudentId, jt.LectureId } )
            .Select(g => new {
                StudentId = g.Key.StudentId,
                LectureId = g.Key.LectureId, 
                CountStudentId =  -1, // Count all StudentId (i.e. 10)?
                CountStudentIdLectureId = g.Count()
            });

        // this is just the printing of the results
        Console.WriteLine(
            "StudentId".PadRight(15) +
            "LectureId".PadRight(15) +
            "CountStudentId".PadRight(17) +
            "CountStudentLectureId".PadRight(15));

        foreach(var x in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 
                x.StudentId.ToString().PadRight(15), 
                x.LectureId.ToString().PadRight(15), 
                x.CountStudentId.ToString().PadRight(17), 
                x.CountStudentIdLectureId.ToString().PadRight(15)));
        }
    }

    public static List<JoinTable> SeedJoinTable()
    {
        var list = new List<JoinTable>();
        var studentId = 0;
        var lectureId = 0;

        // insert 20 records
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            if(i != 0)
            {
                if(i % 10 == 0) 
                {   
                    // 10 of each studentId
                    ++studentId;
                    lectureId = 0;
                }
                if(i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    // 3 of each lectureId per student
                    ++lectureId;
                }
            }

            list.Add(new JoinTable() { 
                StudentId = studentId, 
                LectureId = lectureId 
            });
        }
        return list;
    }

    public class JoinTable
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public int LectureId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Supposing there are no duplicates in the table, then simple group by `StudentId` is what you want: `var query = joinTable.GroupBy(t => t.StudentId);`

Comment: How about this:

   `Console.WriteLine("CountStudentId:" 
                       + joinTable
                         .Select(ab=>ab.StudentId)
                         .Distinct().Count());`

Comment: @KarelFrajtak If I use the `joinTable.GroupBy(t => t.StudentId)`, then how do we also count the grouping on both `StudentId` + `LectureId`. It seems like when we have one we don't have the other.

Comment: @erkaner When we're in the `foreach` loop, we're dealing with `x` now instead of with `joinTable`, so I'm not sure how to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: CountStudentId = g.Select(x => x.StudentId).Count(),

Comment: @SherifAhmed `g.Select(x => x.StudentId).Count()` doesn't work... that just gives the value`3` whereas the expected value is `10`.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You want to do this in one line? Why? `CountStudentId` is just `joinTable.Select(t => t.StudentId).Distinct().Count()`, as simple as that.

Comment: I don't understand from where you get this 10

Comment: @SherifAhmed `10` is the total number of times the specific `StudentId` occurs. I.e. If we were just to group on `StudentId`, then we would receive a count of `10`.

Comment: @ataravati Here is an example question for which doing it in one light might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579120/linq-groupby-with-count/29580723#29580723

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak I've updated the question with a more explicit statement of the results that we want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [working DotNotFiddle that produces the results that you want to achieve](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SJ0ozb).

You will want to group by StudentId and set the value to LectureId. This allows you to get the count of both studentId and studentIdLectureId pairs.

```
        var query = joinTable
        .GroupBy(jt => jt.StudentId, jt => jt.LectureId)
        .Select(x => 
             new {
            StudentId = x.Key,
            CountStudentId = x.Count(),
            LectureIds = x.GroupBy(y => y),
        });
```

This does alter how you will loop through the final list, but will provide you the same data with the same amount of loops:

```
    foreach(var x in query)
    {
        foreach(var lectureId in x.LectureIds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 
                x.StudentId.ToString().PadRight(15), 
                lectureId.Key.ToString().PadRight(15), 
                x.CountStudentId.ToString().PadRight(17), 
                lectureId.Count().ToString().PadRight(15)));
        }
    }
```

If you want to include anything with the lectureId (lecture name, professor, etc.) you can do so like this:

```
        var query = joinTable
        .GroupBy(jt => jt.StudentId, jt => new {LectureId = jt.LectureId, ProfessorId = jt.ProfessorId})
        .Select(x => 
             new {
            StudentId = x.Key,
            CountStudentId = x.Count(),
            LectureIds = x.GroupBy(y => y),
        });
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. Here is a fork of the fiddle that demonstrates when the `studentId` and `lectureId` are both zero, your query shows a count of `4` when the expected count is `3`. I don't know why that is... in due course, maybe together we'll solve this one.

Comment: I updated the code to get the lecture id's in a group. While working through it, I had an iteration with the unique lecture ids being counted for that student, rather than the count of the student/lecture id combinations. I published the wrong one. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Got it. I just needed to make one change in your code.

Comment: If you're interested, there is a related unanswered question here that you might be able to answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579120/groupby-with-count/29580723#29580723