# LINQ GroupBy multiple columns and Count

Tags: linq

Model Class

```
public class tstsStates
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string title{ get; set; }
    public int jcount { get; set; }
    public int DCount { get; set; }
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public Guid PId { get; set; }
    public Guid JId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

My Lambda query

```
List<model> list= _context.Table
    .Include(x => x.Table1)
    .Include(x => x.Table2)
    .Include(x => x.Table2)
    .Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.Table4.Id))
    .Select(x => new model
    {
        Name = x.table.FirstName + "" + x.table.LastName,
        Position = x.table.Title,
        JobId = x.table.Id,
        id= x.Id,
        rId= x.Id,
        Date = x.Date

    }).ToList();   //Till here query works absolutely fine.


// How i can group two columns and get the count.
```

**My Problem:**

1) I am missing the logic of grouping by two columns (PId, jbId), taking count and assigning it back to my model to return it back to view.

2) I am missing the logic of grouping by two columns (pid, mydate), taking dCount and assigning it back to my model to return it back to view.

**My Requirement**

**jcount:** I need to take count of Distinct JobIds from above IEnumerable?

**dcount:** I need to take count of Distinct Date from above IEnumerable?

**Reason:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood, you want to display the JobsCount & Days Count for each person and each having different set of titles, in that case try this:-

```
var result = tstPData.GroupBy(x => new { x.PersonnelId, x.Name , x.Position })
                     .Select(x => new 
                                    {
                                        PersonnelId = x.Key.PersonnelId,
                                        Name = x.Key.Name,
                                        Position = x.Key.Position ,
                                        JobCount = x.Count(),
                                        DaysCount = x.Count() 
                                    });
```

Finally you can enumerate over the result and assign to your Model.

**Update:**

I have created custom data object based on your Model:-

```
List<PersonnelStats> persons = new List<PersonnelStats>
            {
                //Same Job for Alex but different date
                new PersonnelStats { Name="Alex", Position="Dev", JobId= new Guid("11223344-5566-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), PersonnelId = new Guid("11223344-5566-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), Date= new DateTime(2015,03,12)},
                new PersonnelStats { Name="Alex", Position="Dev", JobId= new Guid("11223344-5566-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), PersonnelId = new Guid("11223344-5566-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), Date= new DateTime(2015,03,15)},
                //Two jobs for Mary
                new PersonnelStats { Name="Mary", Position="App", JobId= new Guid("11229944-2356-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), PersonnelId = new Guid("11223344-1567-6565-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), Date= new DateTime(2015,03,13)},
                new PersonnelStats { Name="Mary", Position="App", JobId= new Guid("11229944-3445-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), PersonnelId = new Guid("11223344-1567-6565-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), Date= new DateTime(2015,03,13)},
                //Two jobs for Mark with 1 job being at different dates.
                new PersonnelStats { Name="Mark", Position="Test", JobId= new Guid("11223344-7879-2344-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), PersonnelId = new Guid("11223344-2245-4343-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), Date= new DateTime(2015,03,17)},
                new PersonnelStats { Name="Mark", Position="Test", JobId= new Guid("11223344-5522-2344-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), PersonnelId = new Guid("11223344-2245-4343-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), Date= new DateTime(2015,03,17)},
                new PersonnelStats { Name="Mark", Position="Test", JobId= new Guid("11223344-5522-2344-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), PersonnelId = new Guid("11223344-2245-4343-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), Date= new DateTime(2015,03,18)},
            };
```

And this is the code which gives me the desired output:-

```
            var result = persons.GroupBy(x => new { x.PersonnelId, x.Name, x.Position })
                     .Select(x => new
                     {
                         PersonnelId = x.Key.PersonnelId,
                         Name = x.Key.Name,
                         Position = x.Key.Position,
                         JobCount = x.Select(z => z.JobId).Distinct().Count(),
                         DaysCount = x.Select(z => z.Date.Date).Distinct().Count()
                     });
```

Comment: Yes you understood my point well. However this line "x.Count(z => z.JobId)," gives error "Can not convert System.Guid to Bool and x.Count(z => z.Date.Date) says can not covert System.Date to bool.

Comment: Rahul, thanks for the comments. So you mean to say i need to write two seprate groups like new { x.PersonnelId, x.Name , x.Position, x.JobId } and new { x.PersonnelId, x.Name , x.Position, x.Date } and than take the individual count?  I am not sure about your comment. Kindly update your code based on your comment if possible.

Comment: Rahul, var result = tstPData.GroupBy(x => new { x.PersonnelId, x.Name, x.Position })
                     .Select(x => new
                     {
                         PersonnelId = x.Key.PersonnelId,
                         Name = x.Key.Name,
                         Position = x.Key.Position,
                         JobCount = x.GroupBy(y => new {y.PersonnelId, y.JobId}).Select (y => y.Distinct().Count()),
                         DaysCount = x.GroupBy(y => new { y.PersonnelId, y.Date }).Select(y => y.Distinct().Count())
                     }).ToList();"

Comment: Rahul, Is above you mean by further grouping?

Comment: Well i am not sure what data you're asking. Basically. I have 4 columns. Last two columns (JobCount and DaysCount) has to be calculated based on Personnel. e.g. If personnel worked on 2 different jobs the count should be 2 for JobsCount. Similarly if personnel works on one job but on two different dates than DateCount should be 2 for given personnel. Hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: var result = tstPData.GroupBy(x => new { x.PersonnelId, x.Name, x.Position })
                     .Select(x => new 
                     {
                         PersonnelId = x.Key.PersonnelId,
                         Name = x.Key.Name,
                         Position = x.Key.Position,
                         
                         JobCount = x.Select(y=>y.JobId).Distinct().Count(),
                         DaysOnJob = x.Select(z =>z.Date).Distinct().Count()
                     }).ToList();

Comment: i think i got it working with above code. Is that the logic you're thinking to calculate JobCount and DateCount? There is no anymore sub grouping.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I have maked your answer True since it gives right direction to solve it. :)